# Gatsby.js: gatsby-plugin-google-analytics only firing events in production build

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, gatsby

I'm using the gatsby.js plugin `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` (version 1.0.31), and it only places my tracking code on my site when I run `gatsby build`. In that case, my tracking and click events work as expected.

When I run `gatsby develop`, the tracking code is not put on my page. It would be nice to have this in development mode, as I would love to test my GA click events without having to `gatsby build` every time.

Is there an option that would always add the analytics code, even in development?

Comment: You could load Google Analytics via the [gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager/?=google), then set *includeInDevelopment* to *true* in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the source code of `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` plugin of version 2.0.10 and analytics are dependent on environment variable `NODE_ENV` on for [server sider rendering](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-analytics/src/gatsby-ssr.js#L21) and also [for browser](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-analytics/src/gatsby-browser.js#L3).

So there is no option to set is via options for this plugin. There is a **hacky** solution to set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to `production` using i.e. [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) package.